# React - this.state not updated onSubmit

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.

I'm having an issue when I try to handle a form submit. This is my code:

```
class EditCoffee extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        coffeeshop:'',
        bean:'',
        seeds:'', 
        formData: {
          aroma:'',
          flavor:'',
          acidity:'',
          body:'',
          color:''
        },
      };
    this.handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange = this.handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange.bind(this);
    };
```

this is whats's called `onSubmit()`:

```
  handleEditAroma(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    const {userId, select} = this.props
    const data = {
      aroma: this.state.formData.aroma,
      token: this.props.token
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_edit_coffee/${select}/${userId}`;

    axios.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
      .then((res) => {
        this.clearForm()
        this.getAroma(); // ------------------> state blank when this is called
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
    });

    axios.get(url, { 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
      }).then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
          this.setState({
            coffeeshop: res.data.data[0].coffeeshop,
            seeds: res.data.data[0].seeds,
            bean: res.data.data[0].bean,
          })
      })
        };
```

and this is supposed to update this.state:

```
handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange(event) {
    const obj = this.state.formData;
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(obj);
    console.log(this.state.formData)
    this.validateForm(); 

  };
```

error happens here, as `this.state.formData.aroma` is not updated:

```
  getAroma(event) {
    const {userId, select} = this.props

    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/coffee-aroma/${select}/${this.state.formData.aroma}/${userId}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
      console.log(res.data.message)
      console.log(options.url) 
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1">Edit Coffee</font></h1>
        <h1 className="title is-1">{ this.Capitalize('Aroma') }</h1>
          <form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleEditAroma(event) }>
              <div className="field">
               <input
                name="aroma"
                className="input is-dark is-large"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter value from 0.0 to 1.0"
                //value={this.state.formData.aroma}
                onChange={this.handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange}
                />
              </div>
              <input
              type="submit"
              className="button is-dark is-small is-fullwidth"
              value="Submit"
              />
          </form>
```

when I insert a value at input, state is updated alright. And at console I see:

```
{aroma: "0.5", flavor: "", acidity: "", body: "", color: ""}
```

but when I hit "submit button", I'm getting this error at console:

```
"GET /coffee-aroma/decaf//1 HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

where state value is blank (//), not being updated at submit. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not supposed to mutate state, Reference [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: could you point the error, please?

Comment: I also suspect that `url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/coffee-aroma/${select}/${this.state.formData.aroma}/${userId}`,` is not pointing to `localhost:3000` which is usually what the webpack dev server is set to when using create-react-app. Either set CORS headers on the server or [configure a proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Comment: Nginx Proxy is already configured. All other urls are working

Comment: It Is not working because state is not updated and exact path can’t be found at <Route, not due to lack of proxy config, I suppose. Other urls are working in this same component context. this is not a localhost:3000 issue. you can try to guess or you can just trust me when I say it.

Comment: What I say is that this url, also in the question (handle_coffee/) is working.

Comment: Ah ok, so what are the details in the network tab on the failing request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a stupid mistake.

before `thisgetAroma()`, I had this call:
`this.clearForm()`

which obviously erased all updated states back to `' '`.

Sorry for the inconvenience, all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your state on this way:

`handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange`

```
handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange(event) {
   this.setState(prev => ({ 
    ...prev,
    formData: { 
      ...prev.formData,
      [`${event.target.name}`]: event.target.value
    }
   })
   this.validateForm(); 
  };
```

Comment: could you please use the full `handleCoffeComponentsFormChange()`? Im geting syntax erros with your solution.

Comment: but you havan't use `handleCoffeeComponentsFormChange(event) {....` still getting erros

Comment: `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "," (425:4)`, above `formData`

Comment: it is missing a comma after the `...prev`